# Leftmouseclick on stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a stackpanel with image and button in it. I want to fire event when user clicks on a button in stackPanel. My code in xaml is

```
<StackPanel x:Uid="TemperatureMonitor" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="{DynamicResource InstrumentZweiMesswert}" Height="35">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
             <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnAddUserControl"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>

     <Image Width="35" Height="35" x:Uid="Image_15" Source="/Resources\png\TemperatureMonitor.png"/>
     <Button x:Uid="TemperatureMonitor" Content="Temperatur Monitor" x:Name="TemperatureMonitor" IsEnabled="True" Width="135"/>  
 </StackPanel>
```

And method OnAddUserControl in my viewModel is

```
public void OnAddUserControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //some code             
}
```

The problem it that I don't get into OnAddUserControl. Any ideas why?

I want to fire this event when user makes leftMouseClick on a button. So I don't know why, but RelayCommand also doesn't help and not fires method OnAddUserControl. When I moved iteraction code to my button and it looks like this :

```
<StackPanel Background="Black" x:Uid="TemperatureMonitor" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="{DynamicResource InstrumentZweiMesswert}" Height="35">
    <Image Width="35" Height="35" x:Uid="Image_15" Source="/Resources\png\TemperatureMonitor.PNG"/>
    <Button x:Uid="TemperatureMonitor" Content="Temperatur Monitor" x:Name="TemperatureMonitor" IsEnabled="True" Width="135" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnAddUserControl"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>    
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

i've get during runtime mistake that says "For object Type"DockSite" cannot find methodname "OnAddUserControl"". I will appreciate any ideas or help

Comment: consider using Command or RelayCommand

Comment: Why not use a simple button click event handler ?

Comment: Try giving your StackPanel a Background `Background="Transparent"`.

Comment: i think the problem is you doesn't click on your `StackPanel` you are really click on your Image or Button. Test it simple by setting a Background and you will see there is no visible spot

Comment: @WiiMaxx This should doesn't matter because he uses a RoutedEvent. But without a Background it will not be intercepted.

Comment: @LPL if he click's on the Button Background will also doesn't matter because the Button will set the click as handled right or does it bubble through the button if he doesn't use the ButtonClick_Event?

Comment: @WiiMaxx You are right for bubbling events handled before. But he uses a PreviewEvent wich is tunneling. Here the Button has no chance to mark the event as handled before reaching StackPanel.

Comment: thank you for idea, i'm going to try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RelayCommand for this purpose.
Add RelayCommand.cs to your project.

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _action;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                _action(parameter);
            }
            else
            {
                _action("Hello World");
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And this is your ViewModel. I called this MainWindowViewModel. So, add MainWindowViewModel.cs class to your solution.

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private ICommand m_ButtonCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ButtonCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ButtonCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommand=new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ShowMessage));
    }

    public void ShowMessage(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is your xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Width="220" Content="Click me" Command={Binding ButtonCommand} CommandParameter="StackOverflow" />
</StackPanel>
```

It will show you messageBox after clicking button. So you change your project for handing Button Click event in this way.